# asp.net mvc 3 dataanotation external to the database fields in the model not validating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

How can i make this work like I have 5 fields in my database table .

1. I created a model for validation with datannotations and created the compare password field as well with comparepassword attribute. (now my model has 6 fields including one external field compare password and 5 database fields)
2. I created a view with that model.(User)
3. Now I created a controller as well but the problem arise here that when calling that `ActionMethod` the compiler complains about the external field and tells it cannot find any extension method. How can I create the extension method or solve this error?

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(User Users)
   {

   }
   ```

This is the error I get:

> CS1061: 'MvcApplication1.Models.User' does not contain a definition for 'ComparePassword' and no extension method 'ComparePassword' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcApplication1.Models.User' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My Model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserModel))]
public partial class User { }  
public class UserModel
{
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]        
    [Remote("Username", "User", ErrorMessage = "User Name already exists")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is required")]
    public string vcr_UserName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid Email Address")]
    [Remote("EmailAddress", "User", ErrorMessage = "Email Address already exists")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string vcr_EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^.{3,16}$", ErrorMessage = "The Password length must be between 3 and 16 characters ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string vcr_Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Compare Password")]
    [Compare("vcr_Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match")]
    public string ComparePassword { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string vcr_Country { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Website is required")]
    [Display(Name = "WebSite")]        
    public string vcr_Website { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Expertise")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Expertise is required")]
    public string vcr_Expertise { get; set; }

    public int int_GroupId { get; set; }
    public Boolean bit_Active { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(User Users)
    {
        try
        {

            UserRepository UserRep = new UserRepository();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Users.int_GroupId = 2;
                Users.dtm_CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                Users.bit_Active = true;
                UserRep.Add(Users);
                UserRep.Save();
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch { return View(); }
    }
```

View

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.User
   {
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

}

### Index

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {



  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Users</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.vcr_UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.vcr_UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vcr_UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.vcr_Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.vcr_Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vcr_Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComparePassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ComparePassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComparePassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.vcr_EmailAddress)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.vcr_EmailAddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vcr_EmailAddress)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>

    </fieldset>
```

}

Ok when i click the create i am getting the above error

Comment: Please edit your post and include the **exact** error details.

Comment: no one will really be able to **guess** what is wrong. Please post the relevant code that causes the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "external field"?

One thing that already comes to mind is:

Data annotations for view behaviour should not be placed on a model class.
You should separate your model facing the database from the viewmodel facing the view.
There are numerous articles about that.

If you create a viewmodel, you can add the 6th field there, add the data annotations, have the validation do its thing, etc.

You can use a tool like AutoMapper or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to perform the mapping from model to viewmodel and vice versa, so you don't have to write too much code.

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask...